# Translating virtual memory in x86 with PAE

Tags: memory, x86, translation, ram, virtual-memory

Why does translation from a virtual memory address to a physical address with three-level paging (2-9-9-12, 4K page) require multiplying each page index by 8 before calculating the next one?

For example, if I have the virtual address: 0xabde203 (in binary: 1010 1011 1101 1110 0010 0000 0011).

The first step would be to extract "Page directory pointer table" index, which is represented by the two bits - 10, multiply it by 8 => 10000 and summing its value with the external table physical address in order to find the page directory index.

In a normal x86 virtual translation I understand that the paging is done with two level paging (10-10-12), thus multiplying each index (represented by 10 bits) by 4 (2 bits) would equal to the page size.

But why is multiplication done by 8 when using PAE, how is that representing the page directory table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In traditional 32-bit paging each page directory entry and each page table entry is 4 bytes, so the index is multiplied by 4. In PAE and 64-bit paging, each table entry is 8 bytes, so the index is multiplied by 8.

1024 4-byte entries fit in a 4 KB page, so in two-level paging, each index is 10 bits. 512 8-byte entries fit in a 4 KB page, so in PAE, each index is 9 bits.

Your observation that 4*2^10 is 4K is apt. 8*2^9 is also 4K.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer!  But I still miss something, what about the first 2 bits that represent index in the Page Diectory Pointer? Why are they also.multiplied by 8?

Comment: Same reason—the PDPTEs are 8 bytes each. It doesn’t matter that there isn’t a full page of them.